# KendokendoNumericTextBox Cannot set value

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've upgraded to the new version kendo 2020, solution is working and all controls are working well except kendonumerictextbox. This error showed up when trying to set value to kendonumerictextbox

```
 $('#Taxes').data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(sumTaxes);
```

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined]

Answer (score 1):

This is because  $('#Taxes').data("kendoNumericTextBox") is not defined when you are trying to access it's value.